# Downloading a File from HapiJs Server

Tags: node.js, pdf, hapi.js, pdfkit

I need a little help
I want to generate a pdf report.

I'm using PDFKit Node Module

```
const PDFDocument = require("pdfkit");

function generatePDF(request, reply) {
  let doc = new PDFDocument();
   let path = __dirname + "/payments/" + "filename" + ".pdf";



  doc.text = "Hello World!";
  doc.text = "Hello Me!";
  doc.end();  
  return reply(doc)
       .header('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + 'payments.pdf')  

}
```

On the client-side, I have tried so many things:

1.

```
button.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
        axios.get('/payment-pdf')
            .then(function (response) {
                console.log(response);

            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });

    }, false)
```

2.

```
<a href="/payment-pdf" download>Export</a>
```

How do I download the PDF file?
It seems as a simpe task, but I'm not able to get it done.

Thank you.

Comment: try the answer available in https://stackoverflow.com/a/69364483/791799

Answer (score 2):

`.text` does not look like a string from the examples in the [PDFKit readme](https://github.com/devongovett/pdfkit/blob/master/README.md). It is a function to be used like `doc.text('Hello world!')`.

I tested with the following route:

```
{
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/payment-pdf',
    config: {
        auth: false
    },
    handler: (request: hapi.Request, reply: hapi.IReply) => {
        let doc = new PDFDocument();

        doc.text('Hello world!');
        doc.text('Hello me!');
        doc.end();

        reply(doc)
            .header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=payments.pdf');
    }
}
```

And I used this html to file to download the pdf:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="http://localhost:4200/payment-pdf" target="_blank">Export</a>
</body>
</html>
```